# ISC-DHCPD & BIND9: Adjust hostname for BIND ddns registration

Tags: bind, isc-dhcp

I am running `isc-dhcpd-4.4.1` and `BIND 9.11.6` daemons on FreeBSD 11.2 server for a small company.

`dhcpd` serves a number of Windows stations (assigning them mostly static IP addresses), several special-purpose devices (getting static public IP addresses - must be available to our clients) and also different portable devices connecting the network through WiFi (which get addresses from a predefined range `192.168.120.50 - 192.168.120.200`). The dynamically assigned clients get registered by the BIND `named` and their names are available both for forward and reverse DNS resolution. As the lease time for portable devices is short, they are automatically removed from DNS whenever they cease communicating. 
So far, this arrangement works perfectly. The above text is identical to my recent contribution.

Now I have another question:

Some portable devices ask for lease by their host names that do not conform to standards (e.g., hostname contains '_') which results in DNS registration refusal. Is there any way to correct the registration names by a "filter" (e.g., sed script)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in the options stanza for your bind installation:

```
check-names             master warn;
```

This instructs the bind server to only warn about invalid names, they are added to the zone even though the name is considered illegal.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. It works!